# Guard clause for properties that are possibly forgotten to be assigned a value

Tags: c#, enums, guard-clause

We have a message that is being passed to a method.

```
class Message
{
    public int     TransactionId    { get; set; }
    public bool    IsCredit         { get; set; } // Debit when false
    public decimal Amount           { get; set; }
}

class ServiceBus
{
    public IService TheService { get; set; }

    public void SomethingHappen()
    {       
        var message = new Message
        {
            TransactionId = 7,
            Amount        = 6
            // forgot to assign IsCredit
        };
        TheService.DoSomething(message);
    }
}

class Service
{
    public void DoSomething(Message message)
    {
        // Before proceeding with anything else, wanted to put 
        // a guard clause if something was not assigned, e.g., IsCredit             
    }
}
```

Can't check if IsCredit was forgotten to be assigned of value, as unassigned boolean defaults to false, which means it's a Debit, an assignment of `IsCredit = false;` could not be detected as unassigned, as it indicates a Debit instead.

So I suggested to use a [DrCrFlag](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8187/is-there-a-hypernym-for-debit-credit) which starts with value of 1.

```
public enum DrCrFlag 
{
    Debit  = 1,
    Credit = 2
}
```

That way, the DoSomething method can have a [guard clause](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GuardClause) that checks if message's IsCredit property is forgotten to be assigned just by checking if the enum is zero.

```
public void DoSomething(Message message)
{
    // Before proceeding with anything else, wanted to put 
    // a guard clause if something was forgotten to be assigned, e.g., IsCredit             
    if (message.DrCrFlag == 0) throw new ArgumentException("DrCrFlag is unassigned");
}
```

However, the the data contract could be broken on those client apps that rely on boolean property. So changing boolean to DrCrFlag is not possible.

So then I suggested to use a nullable boolean, which could also break existing client app, but they welcome changing the boolean to nullable boolean more than the changing of boolean to enum.

This can be implemented:

```
class Message
{
    public int     TransactionId    { get; set; }
    public bool?   IsCredit         { get; set; } // Debit when false
    public decimal Amount           { get; set; }
}

public void DoSomething(Message message)
{
    // Before proceeding with anything else, wanted to put 
    // a guard clause if something was forgotten to be assigned, e.g., IsCredit             
    if (message.IsCredit == null) throw new ArgumentException("IsCredit is unassigned");
}
```

Is this the right way to guard against unassigned variable?

Should all actions validate the values being passed to it?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to declare a private member `mIsCredit` of type `bool?`. Then in your getter, you can check the value of private variable and throw exception if it is `null`. That way your public property will remain `bool` type.